# Taking a latent semantic analysis (lsa) object and scoring on new data in R

Tags: r, nlp, predict, lsa

I am running latent semantic analysis (LSA) using textmineR in R. What I'm hoping to get is the document by topic matrix with topics scores by document, which I can do by calling theta from my lsa object (below). However, I am running into challenges taking my created lsa object and using it to score a new dataset (i.e. document term matrix, dtm) so that I can apply my pre-existing topic structures on new data. In the example below, I create two topics, and then when I try to use the same exact dtm (pretending it is a new file for the sake of this example), I get the following error:

`"Error in predict.lsa_topic_model(model, dtm_m) : newdata must be a matrix of class dgCMatrix or a numeric vector"`

I need to use a lsa object to score new text. Is there an easy fix that I'm missing? I haven't had good luck coercing the matrix to a "dgCMatrix". I actually am not aware how to do this with other packages like lsa either. Any help on this approach would be greatly appreciated.

```
file = as.data.frame(matrix( c('case1', 'this is some SAMPLE TEXT!',
'case2',  'and this is the 2nd version of that text...', 
'case3', 'more stuff to talk about'), 
        nrow=3,              
        ncol=2,              
        byrow = TRUE))
names(file) [1] <- 'doc_id'
names(file) [2] <- 'text'

library(tm)
wordCorpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(file))

cleaner <- function (wordCorpus) {
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, removeNumbers)
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, removePunctuation)
  return (wordCorpus)
}
wordCorpus <- cleaner (wordCorpus)

tokenizer <- function(x) 
  NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 1, max = 2))
dtm  <- DocumentTermMatrix (wordCorpus, control = list (tokenize=tokenizer, weighting = weightTfIdf))
dtm_m <- as.matrix(dtm)

library(textmineR)
model <- FitLsaModel(dtm = dtm_m,  k = 2)

#this is what I want to get, but ideally also 
#be able to save the "model" object and use to create this in a new sample`

values <- as.data.frame (model$theta)
values
#pretending my original dataset is a new sample and using predict
values_other <- predict (model, dtm_m)
```

Comment: You can create a dgCMatrix with the Matrix package. Either with `Matrix::sparseMatrix()` or with `Matrix::Matrix(x, sparse= TRUE)`. The first function is the recommended way.

Comment: Great, that answered it. Out of curiosity, why is the first function preferred? I ran the second, but the first requires outlining various inputs from the original matrix.

Comment: The first option gives you more control, but is also a lot more efficient in memory consumption. For small matrices it doesn't matter, but for a bit larger ones, you can run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

For workflows like this, you can pretty safely skip using `tm` altogether and just use `textmineR`'s `CreateDtm` function directly.

See the LSA example as part of `textmineR`'s vignette, which shows this exact workflow. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/textmineR/vignettes/c_topic_modeling.html